# Python not showing decimals

Tags: python

Python is exhibiting a strange behaviour that I didnt witness before, not sure what I did or what happened but basically it doesnt operate in shell with decimals
if i type simple

```
>>> 2/3
0
>>> 3/2
1
```

if i try to format that through % or format() it doesnt do much either, basically it just doesnt recognize any decimal

```
>>> a =2/3
>>> a
0
>>> format(a, '.5f')
'0.00000'
```

I needed a simple division for my code to check something and all of a sudden I encountered something as bizzare as this

I use Python 2.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2, `/` performs "integer division" by default. If you put

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your script, it will do the division you want, which will be the default behavior in Python 3. Alternatively, if you want to stay compatible with old Python versions (not recommended for new code), do

```
2. / 3.
```

or, with variables

```
x / float(y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains my troubles, import function however cause an error but float() works!

Comment: @user1575088: the import has to be done at the top of the script.

Comment: Very strange behavior indeed. I mean it is in fact incorrect, mathematically: 10/3 is absolutely not 3. It should calculate correctly by default and automatically generate a float type result. Why doesn't it? Python is normally so full of a lot of great common sense.

Answer (score 3):

a = 2/3.

or

a = 2./3

At least one number needs to be a float!

Answer (score 2):

You are performing operations exclusively on integers, which means fractional components of numbers are dropped.  You need something like `2.0/3` instead, so floating point arithmetic will be used.